# How to let Linux terminal close automatically at the end of a program?

Tags: centos, terminal, qt

I am using Qt creator to compile and test my C++ code. After the program ends, I have to press the Enter key to close the terminal. It becomes annoying when there are too many terminals on the screen. How do I program it to close automatically upon finishing?

Comment: Perhaps ending your program with [kill(0,SIGHUP)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html), which would send it (and its terminal window) a hang-up signal. ymmv

Comment: This sounds like a feature of the terminal emulator. Which one are you using?

Comment: It is Gnome 3.14